# How do I match on a struct field in order to mutate it in place?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching, mutable-reference

I am trying to mutate `VecDeque` inside a struct. I want to receive an event and delete it from `VecDeque`.

```
pub struct Timeline {
    pub event_loop: Option<VecDeque<Events>>
}

impl Timeline {
    pub fn get_event(&mut self)-> Option<Events> {
        if let Some(mut sequence) = self.event_loop {
           sequence.pop_front()
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

got this error

```text
  --> src/timeline.rs:33:37
   |
33 |         if let Some(mut sequence) = self.event_loop {
   |                     ------------    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: consider borrowing here: `&self.event_loop`
   |                     |
   |                     data moved here
   |                     move occurs because `sequence` has type `VecDeque<Events>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait`
```

I can fix this error by taking ownership of entire object `get_event(&mut self)` change to `get_event(self)`, but this is not an option because after getting 1 event from `get_event()`, the whole object is gone and I am receiving "value used after move"

Comment: Is the compiler message that unclear? It tells you "consider borrowing here" the transfer to a mutable borrow if you want mutable access shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: If you make it like compiler suggests, there will be more errors, it looks like fix but in reality it is not. I thought that it is enough to take object as mutable in argument and it always will be mutable inside this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `&mut`  and remove the `mut`:

```rust
if let Some(sequence) = &mut self.event_loop {
```

Or replace the `mut` with `ref mut`:

```rust
if let Some(ref mut sequence) = self.event_loop {
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks like I need to re-read couple of chapters from The Book again :)